# how to make JQuery event.target selection match regular selection

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the same object returned from these JQuery calls. They are both doing DOM selections on the same `cartList` Jquery object but one is through an event and one is from a regular selector.

```
var cartWrapper = $('.cd-cart-container'); 
var cartBody = cartWrapper.find('.body')      
var cartList = cartBody.find('ul').eq(0);  

cartList.on('click', '.delete-item', function(event){
   obj1 = $(event.target).parents('.product');

}

obj2 = cartList.find('li.parent#seg_bookings_paid\\[1055\\]\\[504\\].product');
```

**consle.log output**

```
obj1 = [li#seg_bookings_paid[1055][504].product, prevObject: o.fn.init[1], context: i.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove.text-danger]

obj2 = [prevObject: o.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "li.parent#seg_bookings_paid[1055][504]"]
```

How do I get obj2 to return the same object as obj1?

**HTML**

```
<div class="cart">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>
        <h2>Cart</h2>
        <span class="undo">Item removed. <a href="#0">Undo</a></span>
      </header>

      <div class="body">
        <ul><li id="seg_bookings_paid[1055][504]" class="product"><div class="delete-item"><a href="#0"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></i></a></div><div class="product-details">July 13: Far To Go<span class="price">0.00</span></div></li>
          <!-- products added to the cart will be inserted here using JavaScript -->
        </ul>
      </div>

      <footer>
        <a href="#0" class="checkout btn"><em>Checkout - $<span>NaN</span></em></a>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML. I doubt the console output is correct, because the second one says the selector was something else than you provided in code.

Comment: I added the HTML. Please note that I coded in hard values for my selectors instead of using the php code to make the problem easier to understand. I think the problem is with my jquery syntax to get the right object and the HTML is irrelevant. Edit: fixed my selector error too.

Answer (score 0):

`[...]` in a selector is used to match attributes. If you want to use it to match these literal characters in the ID you have to escape them.

```
obj2 = cartList.find('li.parent#seg_bookings_paid\\[1055\\]\\[504\\].product');
```

You might consider using a different naming scheme for your IDs, e.g. `seg_bookings_paid-1055-504`, so you don't use characters that have special meaning.

Comment: Thanks...I added that part in by hand to replace a php variable to make it easier to understand my question...looks like I made it more difficult. I will edit with your solution.

Comment: PHP still has to generate a selector string that contains the backslashes.

Comment: Does that mean my output for obj2 is what is returned when JQuery finds no match?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Notice that `obj1` shows the object path before `prevObject`, but `obj2` doesn't show anything there.